# CUDA dynamic parallelism with Driver API

Tags: cuda, dynamic-parallelism

I'm trying to compile and link a dynamic kernel and use it with the **CUDA driver API** on a GK110.

I compile the .cu source file in Visual Studio with the relocatable device code flag and compute_35, sm_35 into a ptx file and then *the CUDA linker adds cudadevrt.lib* (at least it tried to according to the linker invocation). When I do a cuModuleLoad on the ptx .obj it says unsupported device code. There is a also a *.device-link.obj* which seems unrealistically small and non of the driver api functions seem to recognize it as a valid image. When inspecting the ptx file I can see that it generated a call to the kernel launch function according to the CUDA documentation (dynamic parallelism from PTX section).

How can I link the proper device code such that the dynamic kernel invocation works?

(this is CUDA 6.5 on Win64 with VC2013)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do the linking while loading the ptx-file using cuda linker provided by the driver API:

- Compile the cu-source file with relocatable flag to ptx

In your app:

- Create a linker instance with cuLinkCreate()
- Append the ptx-file using cuLinkAddFile() or cuLinkAddData()
- Append cudadevrt.lib using cuLinkAddFile() or cuLinkAddData()
- Call cuLinkComplete() which returns you the binary you can then load as usual (e.g. cuModuleLoadDataEx())
- Destroy the linker instance with cuLinkDestroy()

Comment: Thanks! That did work. Still wondering how to make a pre-linked thing though.

Comment: I've provided an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69144256/1695960) which shows how to make the "pre-linked thing".